# Video Material does not receive colour?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I am using a video as the face of my character: [image: Face]

But as you can see, the face is white. (I want it to be the same colour as his skin) So I made some nodes to fix this:[image: Nodes]

This is what I have done for another one of my characters as you can see here:[image: Other Character]

The only difference is that this character's face is an image not a video. Otherwise, I used the same node setup which worked for this guy.

So my question is, why can't I make the background of the video the same colour as his skin, when I can do it for an image?

Comment: In your node setup you are using the alpha channel as mix factor for your colors. As far as I can tell most video files can't save an alpha channel.You also seem to be mixing it with a white-ish color, which results in the white face you see, above.

Comment: Read this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447

Answer (score 0):

Change **Color1** on your mix node to the color of your character.

Select **Multiply** or **Overlay** instead of Mix in your Mix node.

Disconnect your Alpha from the Image Texture node.

You may need to reverse your Color1 and Color2 in your mix node depending on which option you choose.